# bound on the second eigen value of a d-regular undirected graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $G$ be a $d$-regular undirected and connected graph with $n$ vertices.

Let $A$ be the  normalized adjacency matrix. ($A_{i,j} =$ number of edges between $i$ to $j$ divided by $d$)

Let $B = \frac{1}{2}I + \frac{1}{2}A $

Let $0 \le \lambda_n \le \lambda_{n-1} \le \ldots \lambda_0 = 1 $ be the eigenvalues of v, and $u_1 \ldots u_n$ the corresponding orthonomral eigenvectors

Let $ x = u_2$ be the eigen vector corresponding to $\lambda_1$

A. prove:

$$ \lambda_2 = \langle Bx,x\rangle = \sum_{i,j} B_{i,j}x_ix_j = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j} B_{i,j}(x_i^2 + x_j^2 - (x_i - x_j)^2) = \sum_{i,j} x_i^2 - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j} B_{i,j}(x_i -x_j)^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j} B_{i,j}(x_i -x_j)^2$$

B. show there exists $i$ such that $\lvert x_i \rvert \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $

C. show there exists i and j such that  $x_i \le 0$ and $x_j \ge 0$

D. use the fact the G is connected to show that there exists an edge $(i, j)$ such that $(x_i - x_j)^2 \ge \frac{1}{n^3}$

E. show that $\lambda_2 \le 1 - \frac{1}{4dn^3}$

Part A is pretty stright forward using definitions, and the fact that the sum of each row\column is 1.

I also showed parts B and C using the facts that the vectors are orthonormal.

How to show parts D and E?